# wordpress: How to Get post title for given url?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a separate wordpress table where there is only post url in that.

Now, I want post title from that url.

Tried `<?php $postid = url_to_postid( $url ); ?>` Doesn't seem to be working good. Returns 0 to some of the urls.

Any ideas/suggestions ?

Comment: For which URL's is the function not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
$post_title=$wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='$url'");
```

Or

post_url is a column name

```
$tbl_new='table name where post urls are stored';
$post_title=$wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts a  JOIN $tbl_new b on a.guid=b.post_url WHERE guid='$url'");
```