# Referring Post Title in wordpress template

Tags: wordpress, title, referrer

Does anyone know how to get the title of the referring post on a wordpress site?

For example, I'm creating a form and would like to include the title of the previously visited page/post as a prepopulated field.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function: `wp_get_referer()` which gives you a link to the post. [Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer)

Comment: Thanks! That gives the referring url, how do I now get the title of that page?

Comment: @LewisR. Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26707881/2127296 ? Let me know If it works

Comment: I was able to figure it out using a function to autopopulate a field in gravity forms - https://gist.github.com/mandiwise/ed7cf3209655d122fda0